# Streaming data in Ruby net/http PUT request

Tags: ruby, rest, streaming, put

In the [Ruby-doc Net/HTTP](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) there is a detailed example for streaming response bodies - it applies when you try to download a large file.

I am looking for an equivalent code snippet to upload a file via PUT. Spent quite a bit of time trying to make code work with no luck. I think I need to implement a particular interface and pass it the to `request.body_stream`

I need **streaming** because I want to alter the content of the file while it is being uploaded so I want to have access to the buffered chunks while the upload takes place. I would gladly use a library like http.rb or rest-client as long as I can use streaming.

Thanks in advance!
For reference following is the working non streamed version

```
    uri = URI("http://localhost:1234/upload")

    Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
      request = Net::HTTP::Put.new uri

      File.open("/home/files/somefile") do |f|
        request.body = f.read()
      end

      # Ideally I would need to use **request.body_stream** instead of **body** to get streaming

      http.request request do |response|
        response.read_body do |result|
          # display the operation result   
          puts result
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?  I'm also looking to stream a file using a PUT request so that I can measure upload speed and progress.  Thanks!